# Components of a finite topology.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

My Topology textbook defines components of a topological space X as the equivalence classes under the equivalence relation ~ on X defined by: x ~ y iff x and y are in some connected subset of X.

I have been reading about what is called the specialization preorder.  The specialization preorder is a preorder on a set X defined by x < y iff every open set containing x also contains y.  It appears that for finite topologies the connected components (viewing the preorder as a directed graph) are precisely the components of X defined in my text book.

How do I prove this?  Does it suffice to prove the following statement?:  If every open set containing x also contains y then x and y are in some connected set.  Here is a sketch of my proof.

Suppose BWOC that there are no connected sets in X containing both x and y.  Let U be an open set containing both x and y.  Since U is disconnected then there are nonempty open sets V and W that form a separation of U.  Note that both x and y are in W exclusively or they are in V.  WLOG assume x and y are in V.  Now V is disconnected so there are nonempty open sets A and B that form a separation of V.  Again, x and y must both be in A or must both be in B.  But this process can be repeated indefinitely and must terminate (since X is finite) with x and y being the only elements in some open set C.  But C is connected so we have a contradiction.

Is this a valid proof?  Is there a reference that gives a "better" proof?

Comment: So you claim $x \le y$, then $C_x = C_y$, where $C_x$ denotes the component of $x$. The idea of your proof seems all right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this introduction by May](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/FiniteSpaces.pdf) quite helpful myself. Section 4 discusses connectedness (and it turns out connected is even equivalent to path-conected (in the classical sense) as well.

Comment: OK thanks.  By coincidence, the very paper you mention above is exactly what I was trying to read when this question occurred to me.